# Trouble in understanding the explanation of Dirac-Delta Function by Feynman.

Tags: probability, integration, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

This is quoted from Feynman's Lectures' [Normalization of the states in $x$](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_16.html#Ch16-S4):

> We return now to the discussion of the modifications of our basic equations which are required when we are dealing with a continuum of base states. When we have a finite number of discrete states, a fundamental condition which must be satisfied by the set of base states is
>   $$⟨i|j⟩=δ_{ij}.\tag{16.36}$$
>   If a particle is in one base state, the amplitude to be in another base state is $0.$ By choosing a suitable normalization, we have defined the amplitude $⟨i|i⟩$ to be $1.$ These two conditions are described by Eq. $(16.36).$ We want now to see how this relation must be modified when we use the base states $|x⟩$ of a particle on a line. If the particle is known to be in one of the base states $|x⟩$, what is the amplitude that it will be in another base state $|x'⟩$? If $x$ and $x'$ are two different locations along the line, then the amplitude $⟨x|x'⟩$ is certainly $0,$ so that is consistent with Eq. $(16.36).$ But if $x$ and $x'$ are equal, the amplitude $⟨x|x'⟩$ will **not** be $1,$ **because of the same old normalization problem.** To see how we have to patch things up, we go back to Eq. $(16.19),$ and apply this equation to the special case in which the state $|ϕ⟩$ is just the base state $|x'⟩.$ We would have then
>   $$⟨x'|ψ⟩=\int ⟨x'|x⟩ψ(x)dx.\tag{16.37}$$
>   Now the amplitude $⟨x|ψ⟩$ is just what we have been calling the function $ψ(x).$ Similarly the amplitude $⟨x'|ψ⟩,$ since it refers to the same state $|ψ⟩,$ is the same function of the variable $x',$ namely $ψ(x').$ We can, therefore, rewrite Eq. $(16.37)$ as
>   $$ψ(x')=\int ⟨x'|x⟩ψ(x)dx.\tag{16.38}$$
>   This equation must be true for any state $|ψ⟩$ and, therefore, for any arbitrary function $ψ(x).$ **This requirement should completely determine the nature of the amplitude** $⟨x|x'⟩$—which is, of course, just a function that depends on $x$ and $x′.$
>   Our problem now is to find a function $f(x,x'),$ which when multiplied into $ψ(x),$ and integrated over all $x$ gives just the quantity $ψ(x').$ **It turns out that there is no mathematical function which will do this!** At least nothing like what we ordinarily mean by a “function.”
>   Suppose we pick $x'$ to be the special number $0$ and define the amplitude $⟨0|x⟩$ to be some function of $x,$ let’s say $f(x).$ Then Eq. $(16.38)$ would read as follows:
>   $$ψ(0)=∫f(x)ψ(x)dx.\tag{16.39}$$
>   What kind of function $f(x)$ could possibly satisfy this equation? **Since the integral must not depend on what values $ψ(x)$ takes for values of $x$ other than $0,$ $f(x)$ must clearly be $0$ for all values of $x$ except $0.$** But if $f(x)$ is $0$ everywhere, the integral will be $0,$ too, and Eq. $(16.39)$ will not be satisfied. So we have an impossible situation: we wish a function to be $0$ everywhere but at a point, and still to give a finite integral. Since we can’t find a function that does this, the easiest way out is just to say that the function $f(x)$ is defined by Eq. $(16.39).$ Namely, $f(x)$ is that function which makes $(16.39)$ correct. The function which does this was first invented by Dirac and carries his name. We write it $δ(x).$ All we are saying is that the function $δ(x)$ has the strange property that if it is substituted for $f(x)$ in the Eq. $(16.39),$ the integral picks out the value that $ψ(x)$ takes on when $x$ is equal $0$; and, since the integral must be independent of $ψ(x)$ for all values of $x$ other than $0,$ the function $δ(x)$ must be $0$ everywhere except at $x=0.$ Summarizing, we write $$
> ⟨0|x⟩=δ(x),\tag{16.40}$$
>   where $δ(x)$ is defined by
>   $$ψ(0)=∫δ(x)ψ(x)dx.\tag{16.41}$$
>   Notice what happens if we use the special function “1” for the function $ψ$ in Eq. $(16.41).$ Then we have the result
>   $$1=∫δ(x)dx.\tag{16.42}$$
>   That is, the function $δ(x)$ has the property that it is $0$ everywhere except at $x=0$ but has a finite integral equal to unity. We must imagine that the function $δ(x)$ has such a fantastic infinity at one point that the total area comes out equal to one.

I'm really having problem in understanding the statement of Feynman;"Since the integral must not depend on what values $ψ(x)$ takes for values of $x$ other than $0,$..." Really, why doesn't the integral need not have depend on the values $\psi(x)$ takes for $x$ other than $0$? Can anyone please explain this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I believe when Feynman writes $\int f(x)\psi(x) \,dx$
here, he means $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\psi(x) \,dx$.
Omitting the bounds is a physicist's notational shortcut.

As mentioned earlier with regard to Equation $(16.38)$:

> This equation must be true for any state $|\psi⟩$ and, therefore, for any arbitrary function $\psi(x).$

The equation

$$\psi(0)=\int f(x)\psi(x) \,dx.\tag{16.39}$$

*also* must be true for any arbitrary function $\psi(x).$

So let $f(x)$ be a function that satisfies $(16.39)$ for every
possible function $\psi(x)$;
in particular suppose $(16.39)$ is true when we use some particular
function $\psi(x) = \psi_0(x).$
And suppose $f(x)$ is not zero everywhere except at $x=0$,
or more mathematically, suppose there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ 
(both positive, or both negative) such that
$f(x) > 0$ whenever $a < x < b$.
Let's define $\psi_1(x)$ as follows:

$$\psi_1(x) = \begin{cases}
\psi_0(x) + 100 & \text{if $a < x < b$} \\
\psi_0(x) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

In particular, $\psi_1(0) = \psi_0(0)$ because the interval $[a,b]$
does not include zero.
Then we have

\begin{align}
\int f(x)\psi_1(x)\,dx 
&= \int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx
    + \int_a^b \left(f(x)\psi_0(x) + 100f(x)\right)\,dx 
    + \int_b^\infty f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx \\
&= \left(\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx
    + \int_a^b f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx + \int_b^\infty f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx\right)\\
& \qquad \qquad \qquad   + \int_a^b 100f(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx + \int_a^b 100 f(x)\,dx  \\
&= \psi_0(0) + \int_a^b 100 f(x)\,dx  \\
&= \psi_1(0) + \int_a^b 100 f(x)\,dx \\
&> \psi_1(0)
\end{align}

which says Equation $(16.39)$ is not true for $\psi_1(x)$.

This is just a crude demonstration, not a proof, but the idea is that
if in any way we make $f(x)$ non-zero on some measurable subset of
the positive and negative real numbers, we can construct a
variation of $\psi_0(x)$, call the new function $\psi_1(x)$, such that 
$\int f(x)\psi_1(x)\,dx$ should equal $\psi_1(0)$ according to Equation
$(16.39)$, yet $\int f(x)\psi_1(x)\,dx \neq \psi_1(0)$.
So if we want Equation $(16.39)$ to be true for *every* possible choice
of function $\psi(x)$, we cannot let $f(x)$ have non-zero values over
any such subset of the real numbers, only at zero.

(Somewhere I'm sure there's a rigorous mathematical definition of the
Dirac delta function that patches up the holes in this exposition, but
I can only remember the physicists' version. Since this is for a
Feynman lecture, that seems appropriate anyway.)

Comment: +1; though the derivation is somewhat crude, it was really helpful to me. BTW, can I ask you one more thing: Couldn't Feynman use the kronecker delta? Mean to say why does kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$ fail when there is a continuum of base states?

Comment: The Kronecker delta is useful in a summation. We can't take a _sum_ of a continuum of base states (at least not in the sense of simply adding quantities to each other), so instead we take an integral. If we define a continuous Kronecker delta as $0$ everywhere except at one value of $x$, where it is just $1$, and try to use that instead of the Dirac delta, we end up with an integral that comes to zero.

Comment: Suppose, that 'continuous Kronecker delta' exists. Then how would Dirac-Delta Function be different from that? The later is also $0$ everywhere except at the origin where it is $1$; it seems to me that it is acting the same way as the 'continuous Kronecker delta' would act if it existed that is $0$ everywhere & $1$ at the origin. So, what is the difference between Dirac-Delta Function & the 'Continuous Kronecker Delta'?

Comment: Dirac delta is _not_ equal to $1$ at the origin. It is "infinite". I think the standard mathematical model is that we aren't dealing with a function here, but with a limiting process involving functions with increasingly large values over an ever smaller neighborhood around zero. The _area_ under the function, not its value, is $1$.

Comment: Sorry, sir for again disturbing you; I was re-reading your answer. Though I could easily remember back your words; I didn't quite conceive the integral you wrote in the example. According to me, the integral would be  $$\begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\psi_1(x)\,dx 
&= \int _{-\infty}^a f(x)\psi_0(x)\,dx + \int_a^b f(x)\{\psi_0(x)+100 f(x)\}\,dx  + \int_{b}^{\infty} f(x)\psi_0(x) \, dx \\
&= 3\psi_0(x) + \int_a^b 100 f(x)\,dx  \\
&= 3\psi_1(x) + \int_a^b 100 f(x)\,dx \\ &> 3\psi_1(x)
\end{align}.$$ Why've you used only $100$ for $\psi_1(x)$ when $a <x<b$ instead of $\psi_0(x)+100?$

Comment: I know I've meddled & confused something; I've really made a mistake. Could you please tell me where I've mistaken?

Comment: Remember that $\int f(x)\psi(x)\,dx$ is shorthand for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\psi(x)\,dx$, i.e., integration over the complete real number line. Each of the three integrals you added to make $3\psi_0$ is an integral over just part of the real number line; added together they make just one integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so just $\psi_0(0)$ with no factor of $3$. That's also where I used the $\psi_0(x)$ from $\psi_0(x)+100$. I have expanded the derivation to show more of these steps, and corrected some $x$s that should have been $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the equation $\psi(0)=\int f(x)\psi(x)dx$ only looks at what happens at $\psi(0)$. So, for instance, suppose $\psi_1(x),\psi_2(x)$ are two functions such that $\psi_1(0)=\psi_2(0)$, but $\psi_1(x)\neq\psi_2(x)$ for $x\neq 0$. Then $\int f(x)\psi_1(x)dx=\psi_1(0)=\psi_2(0)=\int f(x)\psi_2(x)dx$. So even though $\psi_2(x)$ and $\psi_1(x)$ were drastically different functions, when integrated against $f(x)$, they returned the same result. That is, it doesn't really matter what happened except at $x=0$.